Android App crashing when using different versions of SO files from different .aar libraries
I have integrated two .aar libraries into my Android application: "libuvccamera-release.aar" for USB camera functionality and "snpe-release.aar" for utilizing the Snapdragon Neural Processing Engine. These libraries contain several ".so" files, including "libc++_shared.so." During the build process, I encountered the following error:
2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so' from inputs

To resolve this error, I attempted to use the
packagingOptions { pickFirst } 

method in my build.gradle file. However, after implementing this solution, my app now crashes when attempting to use the USB camera functionality.
The error log is mainly crash64dump.
I need help resolving this issue without compromising the functionality of either the USB camera or the Snapdragon Neural Processing Engine. How can I properly configure my project to avoid the "2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so' from inputs" error while ensuring that both libraries work as intended in my Android application?

try this android {
...
packagingOptions {
exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
}
} in your gradel

Hello @Ramz Thank You for commenting!
Unfortunately I am using Mapbox map provider which requires the libc++_shared.so library to work.
